# Firefox open new tab behaviour

Tags: firefox, search, browser-tabs, toolbar

When I open a new tab the cursor focuses on the address bar. Is it possible to focus on the search bar by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer to this

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15127/make-firefox-show-google-results-for-default-address-bar-searches/

So now when I open a new tab I can just type the phrase I want to search in the address bar and get the results.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to

```
about:config
```

you can change the setting below (default is false, set to true.)

```
browser.search.openintab
```

Then you can just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to focus on the search box, and then when you hit enter, the search results will open in a new tab.

Comment: I currently use this setup (thanks to tabmixplus) but I'd still like to know how to do what I asked, I guess it's probably not possible. Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: this did not work for me

Comment: Did not work. The cursor in a new window, still starts with the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure of the exact answer to your question, you can change the default search engine that the address bar uses.  [This tutorial](http://www.liewcf.com/modify-firefox-address-bar-search-810/) explains how:

> - At Firefox address bar, enter `about:config` and press ENTER.
> - At `Filter: field`, type `keyword.url`
> - You should see a Preference name of `keyword.URL` in the list. Double click it, a `Enter String Value` input box will appear.
> - Replace the string with: `http://www.google.com.my/search?q=`
> - Click `OK` button and done!

Comment: Hi, thats fairly close but I have a few different search engines that I use regularly so its not really a final solution.

Thanks though.

Comment: This is an old answer that the system flagged in the Low Quality Posts queue, probably because site standards have changed over time and this is just a link to an external answer.  Since it wasn't a solution, it's probably not worth improving, but thought I'd pass on a heads up.

Comment: @fixer1234 Cheers for the heads up. Link was also dead as it happens- did what I could with it.

Answer (score 1):

While not default, the Search Box is one <kbd>TAB</kbd> away from the Awesome Bar in Firefox.
I often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get to the search bar.

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get to the search box when opening a new tab.

Comment: Instead of Ctrl+L you can use Ctrl+K but it's still not quite what I'm looking for.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the New Tab Searchbar addon, which solves exactly this problem. New tabs have focus redirected to the search bar.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-searchbar/

Comment: Oops! We can’t find that page. Apparently, the add-on is gone!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer either, but you can define short keywords to use in the address bar in order to use different search engines. E.g. `su` to search in Super User (through Google) and `w` for Wikipedia (through Google or directly).

To search for UltraEdit on Super User enter in the address bar:

```
su UltraEdit
```

---

How to install:

Bookmark a Google search where you have used `site:superuser.com`, 
e.g. `CPU site:superuser.com`.

Then edit the bookmark (menu Bookmarks/Organize Bookmarks.../Bookmarks Menu/<select the bookmark - it is at the end>):

- Fill out the `keyword` field. E.g. with "su".
- Replace the word you used in the original search (CPU in the example above) with `%s`.

Now searches in Super User can be done directly from the address bar, e.g.:

```
su firefox installer
```

(<kbd>F6</kbd> toggles focus to the address bar.)