# How to set cursor on HTML content when opening new Firefox tab?

Tags: firefox

When I open a new tab in `Firefox`, the cursor is set in the URL (or address) field.  This provides poor `UX` for me as my home page is Google and I would like the cursor to automatically go into the first `form textbox`, which is the search field.  How can I change the Firefox config to change the default cursor position from the URL field to the first form textbox or anywhere in the HTML content when a new tab is opened?

Comment: Related/Possible Duplicate: [Firefox open new tab behaviour](http://superuser.com/questions/123195/firefox-open-new-tab-behaviour)

Comment: unfortunately, those instructions did not work for me

Comment: Which instructions did you try? What were the results?